# gdb/mi gdb server debugging

Tags: gdb, gnu-make, gdbserver, gdbm

**What is the difference between gdb mi and gdb server? Can both be used for local debugging?**

I have facing problem in troubleshooting the debugging with gdb server on Red Hat. The debugging launcher stops at 72 %.

Comment: I stumbled here because of gdb/mi gdb server difference question. I think the answer below is useful. Maybe accept it as appreciation of his help?? :) (Click the check beside it)

Answer (score 5):

For local debugging you need neither MI or gdb server. You only need gdb.

MI is used by various GUIs/IDEs to communicate with gdb. This basically changes commands so they can be better parsed by machines (hence the name Machine Interface).

Gdbserver is used to debug remote systems. You only run gdbserver on remote (target) machine (this can for example be some embedded system running linux) and then you connect to gdbserver from GDB on your workstation (serial, ethernet or similar). This allows you to debug on your workstation and only requires target to run simpler gdbserver.

Comment: Hi @dbrank0, it worked for me after choosing 'gdb server', am using Fedora-21 32 bit OS and Eclipse Luna. Thanks for the comments. up-voted!